# Python set loog as a variable

Tags: python

I have assignment where I need to get all data from api using ids. Here is my code so far:

```
import json, requests

ids = [
'tt0111161',
'tt0068646',
'tt0071562',
...
]

for i in ids:
    url = 'http://www.omdbapi.com/?i={}'.format(ids)+apikey

r = requests.get(url)
val = json.loads(r.text)
print val
```

The problem is that the code is printing out details only about last id and I don't really know where my mistake is. I want to iterate by all ids list and print data about each one separately.

Comment: Is the indentation in your code exactly as in the code posted above?

Comment: move your last part `r= ...` inside the `for loop`. And your code will work.

Comment: Just correct the indentation and you are good. Put those lines from requests in for loop.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are substituting ids in url in a loop but running requests.get only once because of the indentation - indent the last 3 lines to the level of the body of the for and things will be as you expect them to be.

Answer (score 0):

If the code you posted is exactly as posted, indent the stuff you want to happen in a loop, so that it is clearly in the loop

```
import json, requests

ids = [
'tt0111161',
'tt0068646',
'tt0071562',
...
]

for i in ids:
    #url = 'http://www.omdbapi.com/?i={}'.format(ids)+apikey
    url = 'http://www.omdbapi.com/?i={}'.format(i)+apikey
    #                                           ^--- did you mean current ids here?  

    r = requests.get(url)
    val = json.loads(r.text)
    print val
```